# which “pactl” : audio source is “curently playing” one

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'd like to capture the audio comming out of my soundcard, with :

```
gst-launch -v ! pulsesrc device=X ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! webmmux ! filesink location=audio.mkv
```

I don't know which source X to give as argument, pactl gives me to many to try them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list the default sink we can issue

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

The default sink is marked with an asterisk `*`:

```
>>> 2 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_02_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1>
```

Adding `.monitor` to the default sink will give us an input source for this sink.

In case we need to know where a stream is currently playing we can issue:

```
pacmd list-sink-inputs
```